# select JS menu behaves different in server than in my own desktop

Tags: javascript, mobile, select-menu

I published my web some weeks ago...But as I looked my web in my mobile phone (I made @mediaquerie for mobile) I could see that the JS select menu behaved really strange (it appears 4 times and different than in my desktop)...You can see here in these two images the difference...

[Mobile version of my web in my desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFznB.jpg)

[Mobile version of my web in the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETSk3.jpg)

And here is the web if you want to look into the code: www.elenacostasoprano.com/contact.html

(it happens in all the pages).

Does anyone know what could be the problem in the code?

Comment: in your media queries there is a gap between the 600px and 768px mark. This is why the elements aren't being styled.

Comment: Jeff, sorry, I can't see that ! But all the rest of the elements are styled except the select-menu, wich behaves strange in the server (but not in my computer)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you actually are including the `select` four times.

Infact, if you have a look into the navigation menu you'll see

```
<nav>
        <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bio</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="biography.html">Biography</a></li>
                        <li><a href="repertoire.html">Repertoire</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>   
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="media.html">Media</a></li>
                        <li><a href="photos.html">Photos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>    
                <li><a href="agenda.html">Agenda</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    <select><option selected="selected" value="">Go to...</option><option value="index.html">Home</option><option value="#">Bio</option><option value="biography.html">Biography</option><option value="repertoire.html">Repertoire</option><option value="#">Gallery</option><option value="media.html">Media</option><option value="photos.html">Photos</option><option value="agenda.html">Agenda</option><option value="contact.html">Contact</option><option value="https://www.facebook.com/elenacostasoprano">
        </option><option value="https://twitter.com/elenacpsoprano">
        </option><option value="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoRkjY7OEQFSs7KwmruUVPw">
        </option><option value="https://plus.google.com/u/0/115736588985404106684/about/p/pub">
        </option><option value="https://www.instagram.com/elenacostasoprano/">
        </option><option value="contact.html">EN</option><option value="de/kontakt.html">DE</option><option value="es/contacto.html">ES</option></select></nav>
    <nav>
        <select onchange="window.location.href=this.value;"> 
            <option value="index.html">Home</option>
            <option value="biography.html">Biography</option> 
            <option value="repertoire.html">Repertoire</option>
            <option value="media.html">Media</option>
            <option value="photos.html">Photos</option>
            <option value="agenda.html">Agenda</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="contact.html">Contact</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="">Go to...</option><option value="index.html">Home</option><option value="#">Bio</option><option value="biography.html">Biography</option><option value="repertoire.html">Repertoire</option><option value="#">Gallery</option><option value="media.html">Media</option><option value="photos.html">Photos</option><option value="agenda.html">Agenda</option><option value="contact.html">Contact</option><option value="https://www.facebook.com/elenacostasoprano">
        </option><option value="https://twitter.com/elenacpsoprano">
        </option><option value="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoRkjY7OEQFSs7KwmruUVPw">
        </option><option value="https://plus.google.com/u/0/115736588985404106684/about/p/pub">
        </option><option value="https://www.instagram.com/elenacostasoprano/">
        </option><option value="contact.html">EN</option><option value="de/kontakt.html">DE</option><option value="es/contacto.html">ES</option></select> 

    <select><option selected="selected" value="">Go to...</option><option value="index.html">Home</option><option value="#">Bio</option><option value="biography.html">Biography</option><option value="repertoire.html">Repertoire</option><option value="#">Gallery</option><option value="media.html">Media</option><option value="photos.html">Photos</option><option value="agenda.html">Agenda</option><option value="contact.html">Contact</option><option value="https://www.facebook.com/elenacostasoprano">
        </option><option value="https://twitter.com/elenacpsoprano">
        </option><option value="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoRkjY7OEQFSs7KwmruUVPw">
        </option><option value="https://plus.google.com/u/0/115736588985404106684/about/p/pub">
        </option><option value="https://www.instagram.com/elenacostasoprano/">
        </option><option value="contact.html">EN</option><option value="de/kontakt.html">DE</option><option value="es/contacto.html">ES</option></select></nav>
    <div id="extras">
    <div id="socialcontainersup">
    <p>
    <a title="Follow me on Facebook!" href="https://www.facebook.com/elenacostasoprano" target="_blank">
        <img style="margin-right:0px; margin-left:0px;" src="images/facebookmovil.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/facebookmovilhover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/facebookmovil.png'" alt="Facebook" width="32" height="32"></a>
    <a title="Follow me on Twitter!" href="https://twitter.com/elenacpsoprano" target="_blank">
        <img style="margin-right:0px; margin-left:0px;" src="images/twittermovil.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/twittermovilhover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/twittermovil.png'" alt="Twitter" width="32" height="32"></a>

    <a title="Subscribe to my YouTube channel!" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoRkjY7OEQFSs7KwmruUVPw" target="_blank">
        <img style="margin-right:0px; margin-left:0px;" src="images/youtubemovil.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/youtubemovilhover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/youtubemovil.png'" alt="Youtube" width="32" height="32"></a>

    <a title="Follow me on GooglePlus!" href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/115736588985404106684/about/p/pub" target="_blank">
        <img style="margin-right:0px; margin-left:0px;" src="images/googleplusmovil.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/googleplusmovilhover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/googleplusmovil.png'" alt="GooglePlus" width="32" height="32"></a>
    <a title="Follow me on Instagram!" href="https://www.instagram.com/elenacostasoprano/" target="_blank">
        <img style="margin-right:0px; margin-left:0px;" src="images/instagrammovil.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/instagrammovilhover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/instagrammovil.png'" alt="Instagram" width="32" height="32"></a>
    </p>
    </div>
    <div id="language">

        <span class="langswitcher">
            <a class="active" href="contact.html">EN</a>
            |
            <a href="de/kontakt.html">DE</a>
            |
            <a href="es/contacto.html">ES</a>
        </span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <h3>Contact</h3>

<select><option selected="selected" value="">Go to...</option><option value="index.html">Home</option><option value="#">Bio</option><option value="biography.html">Biography</option><option value="repertoire.html">Repertoire</option><option value="#">Gallery</option><option value="media.html">Media</option><option value="photos.html">Photos</option><option value="agenda.html">Agenda</option><option value="contact.html">Contact</option><option value="https://www.facebook.com/elenacostasoprano">
        </option><option value="https://twitter.com/elenacpsoprano">
        </option><option value="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoRkjY7OEQFSs7KwmruUVPw">
        </option><option value="https://plus.google.com/u/0/115736588985404106684/about/p/pub">
        </option><option value="https://www.instagram.com/elenacostasoprano/">
        </option><option value="contact.html">EN</option><option value="de/kontakt.html">DE</option><option value="es/contacto.html">ES</option></select></nav>
```

where there are four select menu that are shown using this media query

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
  nav ul     { display: none; }
  nav select { display: inline-block; }
} /*Note: This last bracket miss in the original css*/
```

which basically means "Hide every `ul` and show every `select` element placed inside a `nav` element".

To resolve the issue, you can just get the rid off of every `select` but one.

Please also notice that there are several error both in the html and in the css.
Use a validator to help you find those issues and correct them. There's plenty of them online, like [this one](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.elenacostasoprano.com%2Fcss%2Festilos7.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en) (for CSS)

Best!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I already saw that code in my web, but the original code in my desktop isn't that, I didn't write the "select menu" four times! The code is as follows...[Select menu and css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2vvY.jpg)

Here you can see the code in my desktop isn't like that and I alredy used that code also in the css...So in my desktop worked perfectly!